# Facing Connectivity Issues: Laravel Application Unable to Connect to RDS Using Secrets and ConfigMap in EKS Deployment

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-rds, amazon-eks

I've deployed a Laravel application on Amazon Elastic Kubernetes Service (EKS) using a node group. To manage sensitive information, I've created secrets and a configmap and included them in my deployment. Additionally, I've created an Amazon RDS (Relational Database Service) instance within the same Virtual Private Cloud (VPC) as the EKS cluster.

**Error**

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (Connection: mysql, SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from 'users' where 'email' = jhon@gmail.com) in file /var/ www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php on line 829

#0 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(983):

Illuminate\Database\Connection-&gt; runQueryCallback(&#039; select count(*)... &#039;, Array, Object
```

Below are the YAML files for my deployment, secret, and configmap:

**deployment.yml file:**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ecom-deployment
  namespace: ecom-eks
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: ecom
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: ecom
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: ecom
        image: public.ecr.aws/v9v3b4i5/ecom-api:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8010
        envFrom:
        - configMapRef:
            name: ecom-configmap
        env:
        - name: DB_USERNAME
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: ecom-secret
              key: db_username
        - name: DB_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: ecom-secret
              key: db_password
```

**secret.yml:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: ecom-secret
  namespace: ecom-eks
type: Opaque
data:
  db_username: rds_username
  db_password: rds_password
```

**configmap.yml:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: ecom-configmap
  namespace: ecom-eks
data:
  APP_NAME: Laravel
  APP_ENV: local
  APP_KEY: 'base64:BPCsfQr+Wk46OcItjF0tXeHI8088jJA1Dr218vfL7is='
  APP_DEBUG: 'true'
  APP_URL: http://localhost

  LOG_CHANNEL: stack
  LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL: null
  LOG_LEVEL: debug

  DB_CONNECTION: mysql
  DB_HOST: ecom.c7ebhqk.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com
  DB_PORT: '3306'
  DB_DATABASE: ecom

  BROADCAST_DRIVER: log
  CACHE_DRIVER: file
  FILESYSTEM_DISK: local
  QUEUE_CONNECTION: sync
  SESSION_DRIVER: file
  SESSION_LIFETIME: '120'

  MEMCACHED_HOST: 127.0.0.1

  REDIS_HOST: 127.0.0.1
  REDIS_PASSWORD: null
  REDIS_PORT: '6379'

  MAIL_MAILER: smtp
  MAIL_HOST: mailpit
  MAIL_PORT: '1025'
  MAIL_USERNAME: null
  MAIL_PASSWORD: null
  MAIL_ENCRYPTION: null
  MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS: 'hello@example.com'
  MAIL_FROM_NAME: "${APP_NAME}"

  PUSHER_APP_ID: ''
  PUSHER_APP_KEY: ''
  PUSHER_APP_SECRET: ''
  PUSHER_HOST: ''
  PUSHER_PORT: '443'
  PUSHER_SCHEME: https
  PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER: mt1

  VITE_PUSHER_APP_KEY: "${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
  VITE_PUSHER_HOST: "${PUSHER_HOST}"
  VITE_PUSHER_PORT: "${PUSHER_PORT}"
  VITE_PUSHER_SCHEME: "${PUSHER_SCHEME}"
  VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER: "${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

I've verified the values of the configmap and secrets by accessing the pod and printing the environment variables. Additionally, I've confirmed RDS connectivity by using the command:

```
mysql -h ecom.c7ebhqk.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -u admin -p xxxxx
```

This successfully connects me to the database.

However, the issue arises when attempting to save data through any API within the Laravel project. I consistently encounter connection errors.

I need guidance on debugging this issue and resolving it effectively. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You said issues when saving data. How about when fetching data from db to your laravel blade/frontend?

Comment: I have created API's in laravel, like when i hit signin or register route in postman then getting issue regarding connection with RDS

Comment: I want to build connection between RDS and my Laravel deployment through configmap and secrets, I'm facing issue regarding connection

Comment: What is the exact error? Post it in your question